# NUnit in Visual Studio 2010 in the tools option

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I have installed the Nunit but it is not showing in the Tools menu of VS 2010. Please help me

Comment: what package did you install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Integrating the NUnit in VS 2010. [Click here](http://www.marthijnvandenheuvel.com/2010/06/09/using-nunit-in-visual-studio-2010/).

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate NUnit into VS 2010 via what @Bili found.  I prefer using Resharper's test runner (but that costs a lot of money).  NCrunch is a free plug-in (for now) that augments NUnit's testing.  In addition to running unit test's it also provides code coverage.  I believe it is a NuGet package.

http://www.ncrunch.net/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some macros that runs NUnit tests.
it supposed to be private so i have some assumptions and it is not that "clean" (i didn't work on it for long)... but if you want to follow them you can get a very comfortable way to "integrate" the tests in VS

Assumptions:

- You have to have NUnit bin folder in PATH environment variable
- Testing project "someName" will be on the "someName.Test" project (for integration tests - "someName.integration")

If you think it might make your work easy so the code is here:

```
    Imports System
    Imports EnvDTE
    Imports EnvDTE80
    Imports EnvDTE90
    Imports EnvDTE90a
    Imports EnvDTE100
    Imports System.Diagnostics
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.IO



    Public Module NUnitExtensions
        Sub AttachToNUnit()
            Dim attached As Boolean = False
            Dim proc As EnvDTE.Process

            For Each proc In DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses
                If (Right(proc.Name.ToLower(), 9) = "nunit.exe") Then
                    proc.Attach()
                    attached = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

        End Sub

        Private Sub RunNunitFile(ByRef dll)
            Dim args = """" & dll & """" & " /run"
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("nunit.exe", args)
        End Sub

        Private Function GetSolutionFiles(ByRef filePattern) As String()
            Dim solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(DTE.Solution.FullName)
            Dim nunitFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(solutionDir, filePattern, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Return nunitFiles
        End Function

        Private Function GetDllCompilationAttributes(ByRef dllFullPath) As Boolean()
            Dim ActiveDoc As Document = DTE.ActiveDocument
            Dim Proj As Project = ActiveDoc.ProjectItem.ContainingProject
            Dim config As Configuration = Proj.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration
            Dim result(2) As Boolean
            result(0) = False
            result(1) = False
            Dim parts = Split(dllFullPath, "\")
            For Each part As String In parts
                If part.ToLower() = "obj" Then
                    result(1) = True
                End If
                If part.ToLower() = config.ConfigurationName.ToLower() Then
                    result(0) = True
                End If
            Next
            Return result
        End Function

        Sub RunNUnit()

            Dim nunitUnitTestFiles = GetSolutionFiles("*test.dll")
            Dim nunitIntegrationTestFiles = GetSolutionFiles("*integration.dll")

            Dim unitTestsAndIntegrationTestFiles As New List(Of String)

            unitTestsAndIntegrationTestFiles.AddRange(nunitUnitTestFiles)
            unitTestsAndIntegrationTestFiles.AddRange(nunitIntegrationTestFiles)

            For Each dll As String In unitTestsAndIntegrationTestFiles
                Dim dllAttributes = GetDllCompilationAttributes(dll)
                Dim debug = dllAttributes(0)
                Dim obj = dllAttributes(1)

                If debug AndAlso Not obj Then
                    RunNunitFile(dll)
                End If

            Next

        End Sub

        Sub RunCurrentProjectNUnit()

            Dim ActiveDoc As Document = DTE.ActiveDocument
            Dim Proj As Project = ActiveDoc.ProjectItem.ContainingProject
            Dim config As Configuration = Proj.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration

            Dim projectFileName = Proj.FullName
            Dim projectPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(projectFileName)
            Dim dllName = Proj.Name

            If (Not projectPath.ToLower().EndsWith(".test")) Then
                projectPath += ".Test"
                dllName += ".Test"
            End If

            Dim testDllPath = String.Format("{0}\bin\{1}\{2}.dll", projectPath, config.ConfigurationName, dllName)

            RunNunitFile(testDllPath)
        End Sub
    End Module
```

Make sure that if you add it to the macro window (Alt+F8) you must name the code file "NUnitExtensions" and then you can add those macros as toolbar buttons for example

Answer (score 0):

The [Visual NUnit](http://www.bubblecloud.org/visualnunit) extension is very helpful; it adds a toolbox for running NUnit tests.